# How do I get the output to display inside the div after the user fills in the prompts?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, output

When I test this code in a browser the prompts pop up just fine, but then there's nothing on the screen after filling them all out. Is there something I'm missing...?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mad Libs</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="out"></div>
        <script>
        var properName = prompt("Enter a proper name");
        var verb = prompt("Enter a verb (past tense)");
        var verb2 = prompt("Enter a second verb (past tense)");
        var adj = prompt("Enter an adjective");
        var adj2 = prompt("Enter another adjective");

        var out = "Roses are red. Violets are blue. <br/>";
        out += properName + "left town without wearing a shoe. <br/>";
        out += properName + " " + verb + "<br/>";
        out += "And " + properName + " " + verb2 + "<br/>";
        out += "But I am " + adj + " " + properName + "thought. <br/>";
        out += "And kind of " + adj2 + " too!";
            
        document.getElementByID('out').innerHTML = out;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementByID` should be `document.getElementById`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mad Libs</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="out"></div>
        <script>
        var properName = prompt("Enter a proper name");
        var verb = prompt("Enter a verb (past tense)");
        var verb2 = prompt("Enter a second verb (past tense)");
        var adj = prompt("Enter an adjective");
        var adj2 = prompt("Enter another adjective");

        var out = "Roses are red. Violets are blue. <br/>";
        out += properName + "left town without wearing a shoe. <br/>";
        out += properName + " " + verb + "<br/>";
        out += "And " + properName + " " + verb2 + "<br/>";
        out += "But I am " + adj + " " + properName + "thought. <br/>";
        out += "And kind of " + adj2 + " too!";
            
        document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = out;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```